# NMinimize function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I tried using NMinimize function to find the global minimum of the following function.

```js
f = {s1 - Log[1000/{Norm[{2.83, 0, 2} - {u, v, w}]}^3]}^2 + {s2 - 
      Log[1000/{Norm[{0, 2.83, -2} - {u, v, w}]}^3]}^2 + {s3 - 
      Log[1000/{Norm[{-2.83, 0, 2} - {u, v, w}]}^3]}^2 + {s4 - 
      Log[1000/{Norm[{0, -2.83, -2} - {u, v, w}]}^3]}^2;
NMinimize[f, {u, v, w}, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}].
```

The optimization is an unconstrained optimization. The following is the error I get each time I run it.

> "NMinimize::nnum: "The function value {{2.67476}} is not a number at
>   {u,v,w} = {0.673558,0.659492,0.0861047}"

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Also is there a way to set the stopping rule and to extract the values from the NMinimize output when there is an error of this kind.
Please help me in debugging this code.
Thank you in advance for the help
Kum.

Comment: @rcollyer - you're really getting into the syntax highlighting, I see :)

Comment: @Verbeia, I figure if I'm editing it anyway, I might as well make it more readable.  It's not perfect, but it works enough.

Answer (score 5):

Curly braces mean lists in Mathematica, so your function is outputting a one-element matrix, not a scalar. Change the pairs of `{}` you are using for grouping into normal parentheses. The fact you are getting double curly braces shows that there are two levels of braces to convert.

```
f = (s1 - Log[1000./(Norm[{2.83, 0, 2} - {u, v, w}])^3])^2 + (s2 - 
      Log[1000./(Norm[{0, 2.83, -2} - {u, v, w}])^3])^2 + (s3 - 
      Log[1000./(Norm[{-2.83, 0, 2} - {u, v, w}])^3])^2 + (s4 - 
      Log[1000./(Norm[{0, -2.83, -2} - {u, v, w}])^3])^2;
```

As a further remark, I'd change the `Integer` values (`1000`) into real numbers (`1000.`), since the rest of the input is in machine-precision real numbers. As Brett reminded me in the comments, the output won't be any different, but if you are doing a lot of repeated calculations, you might notice a small performance speed-up, and you can more easily [Compile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) the function if you want further performance improvements.

(Edited when I realised it was a 1*1 matrix output, not a vector output.)

Comment: `1000` vs. `1000.` shouldn't make any difference here--it'll all get coerced to machine precision anyway.

Comment: @BrettChampion - you are quite right that the output will be the same, but there will be a small performance speed-up, which is what I meant but managed to leave out of the edit. I'll make it clearer in the answer.

Comment: Using `1000.` instead of `1000` is speeding it up by about 0.2% on my machine (using random values for s1, s2, s3, s4.)  Whereas it's 35% faster if I use `h = Simplify[f, Element[u|v|w, Reals]]` to get rid of the norms and associated absolute values (that get squared away....)

Comment: @Verbeia and Thanks a lot for the help!!!! Changing to the normal parentheses really helped its working now :)

Comment: @BrettChampion  And as mentioned the simplify function is really making things move faster. :) Thank you once again.

Comment: I have one last question is there a way to extract the u,v and w from the output list of NMinimize. I used u1=u/.Last[NMinimize[...]]. But when I use this within a for loop Mathematica gives an error message-"Tag is protected Last[NULL] is neither a list of rules". Please help me in this regard. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: @user1000022 please pose this as a separate question. welcome to StackOverflow, don't forget to read the FAQ and click the checkmark next to the answer you find most helpful on a question you asked, and up vote any others that were also useful.